# PostgreSQL: How are results (with JOINs) sent over the network?

Tags: postgresql, networking, join

If I make a query that joins *m* rows onto each of *n* results, I will get a total of *n*m* result rows (each result will have *m* rows joined onto it).

If I am connecting over a network, will *n*m* rows be sent over the network, or is the PostgreSQL software smart enough to represent it in a shorter way? (i.e. n1 * (m1, m2, m3) instead of n1m1, n1m2, n1m3, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the short answer is *no*.

From the [Postgres Message Flow](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-flow.html) doc:

> In simple Query mode, the format of retrieved values is always text,
>   except when the given command is a FETCH from a cursor declared with
>   the BINARY option. In that case, the retrieved values are in binary
>   format. The format codes given in the RowDescription message tell
>   which format is being used.

For *extended query mode*:

> Bind also specifies the format to use for any data returned by the
>   query; the format can be specified overall, or per-column.

Regarding the *RowDescription* message:

> Indicates that rows are about to be returned in response to a SELECT,
>   FETCH, etc query. The contents of this message describe the column
>   layout of the rows. This will be followed by a DataRow message for
>   each row being returned to the frontend.

So this format could be *binary* or pure text, but I don't believe there is any kind of factored-out encoding as you mentioned. That is, it will lay out all of the columns in the specified format, which in the above case would be `(n1, n2, n3, m1, m2, m3)`.